# Oracle get ratio of nulls for each column grouped by specific variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to get an overview of how well my table is populated for each variable grouped by a specific variable so something like:

```
SELECT AVG(VAR IS NOT NULL) * 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_var;
```

or in pandas:

```
my_table.groupby('my_var').apply(lambda x : x.isnull().mean())
```

Hope you can help me I'm pretty new to SQL..

Comment: If by 'variable' you mean 'column' then this is something already tracked by the column statistics. Compare `user_tab_columns.num_nulls` with `user_all_tables.num_rows` (assuming your stats are up to date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT my_var, AVG (CASE WHEN value is null then 0 else 1 end) as ratio
 FROM my_table
 GROUP BY my_var
```